# Is there an quivelant to a Tab Control in Linux Monodevelop?

Tags: linux, user-interface, monodevelop, tabcontrol, gtk#

Easy question: I'm new to Linux Desktop Application Development coming from a Microsoft Windows and Visual Studio Desktop Application Development background and am trying to make a basic GUI application in Monodevelop C# that has what's called a Tab Control in Visual Studio. I can't for the life of me though find an equivalent control in Monodevelop under either Containers or Widgets in the Toolbox and Google has been no help. Am I missing something obvious or is a Tab Control an outdated object, design wise, and has been replaced with something else? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you are working on a GTK# app, and GTK does have a similar control called notebook https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. Looks like it was obvious and I just missed it in the list of containers. Many thanks!